# Visualforce Homepage component

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

I wrote a VF page which I use as a VF Homepage Component on the Narrow Side (Side bar).
Showheader and sidebar page attributes are set to FALSE.
My page uses the standard controller of one of my custom objects.

When I'm on the homepage or any tab the component displays properly BUT when I navigate to any record detail page the component is showing the header and sidebar as well (it seems as the entire SF homepage is showing in the space I allocated to the component)

Why is this happening?
How can I solve this?

Comment: Dedo, did you ever find a resolution to your problem?  I am experiencing exactly the same problem.

Comment: No, I didn't find...

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because the links open within the iframe component. You need redo your vf page to change the links to call a Javascript function on the page that then sets the

window.parent.location

= to the actual url of the clicked link. Then the main window should navigate to the link

Answer (score 1):

If you can get access to the links as HTML instead of relying on the SFDC links, you can put a "target" element in them to open in the whole window.

So instead of

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Account}" />
```

you can do like:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!Account.Id" target="_top">
    <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}">
</apex:outputLink">
```

Comment: I don't have links in on my page - only labels, input fields and 2 buttons

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Can you post some screenshots and the code? If you've fixed it, can you post the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The reason was found; I cannot explain why but removing the standard controller and writing a custom one solves the problem